# Checking if in array key equals to value

Tags: php, api

Hey I got small problem i looking for fast php solution for my problem.
So I got array like this :

```
services: [
    {
    service_id: 8,
    service_name: "Air Condition - Cleaning",
    service_time_realisation: "30",
    service_price: "300"
    },
    {
    service_id: 6,
    service_name: "Carpet Cleaning",
    service_time_realisation: "10",
    service_price: "100"
    }
    ],
```

How I can check that each object service_id in this array is for example '7' ?

could you help me with that please ? ;)

Comment: Um… iterate over each object and check?

Comment: what u try so far?

Comment: Ok Its already ok ;) I figure out something good :P

Answer (score 0):

Try next approach:

```
function checkJson($json, $id)
{
    foreach(json_decode($json, true) as $service) {
        if($service['service_id']!=$id) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
$str = '[
    {
    service_id: 8,
    service_name: "Air Condition - Cleaning",
    service_time_realisation: "30",
    service_price: "300"
    },
    {
    service_id: 6,
    service_name: "Carpet Cleaning",
    service_time_realisation: "10",
    service_price: "100"
    }
]';
$result = checkJson($str, 7);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$retour =  false;
foreach($services as $row){
    if($row['service_id'] == 7){
        $retour = true;
    }
}
```

If retour == true the data contains 7.